# Is there a way to use the Invidious API to create a playlist RSS feed?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, rss

Not sure where to ask this, but I'm trying to use RSS to handle all my YouTube subscriptions and playlists (which I can search through in Emacs, via the elfeed package).

Although I can find the RSS feed for a playlist, the feed only contains the first ~ 15 videos, which is not ideal for longer lists. I'm not sure how, but could I use the Invidious API to create a more complete RSS feed for a given playlist?

I've also found (and modified) [this script](https://github.com/iv-org/invidious/issues/360):

```
#!usr/bin/bash

playlistId=$1


index=0;
page=1;
let "videoCount=$(curl -s https://invidio.us/api/v1/playlists/$playlistId | jq -r ".videoCount")";
while [ $index -le $videoCount ]; do
    curl -s https://invidio.us/api/v1/playlists/$playlistId\?page\=$page | jq -r '"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(.videos|.\[\].videoId)"' ;
    let "page++" ; 
    let "index += 100"; 
done
```

which doesn't quite work for me but I can see roughly how it would help.

I think the alternative is to try to use a particular invidious instance, e.g. https://invidious.protokolla.fi/playlist?list=UUXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw